# A word for the job a cashier does for each customer

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, past-participles

> A cashier in a grocery store has *_*_ 80 customers today.

- *Expedited?*
- *Served?*
- *Handled?*

I have a feeling there's a better word.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think *served* is the only word that really works here. The ambiguity of *handled* leaves one open for the Beavises and Buttheads of the world to snicker and joke, while *expedited* has an entirely different meaning, one that doesn't take human beings as direct objects. Processes, requests, directives — all these can be expedited, but not people.

I see @beetstra has offered *helped* as a synonym, and that may work in some cases. But *helped* implies that one has assisted someone, not necessarily sold someone something.

@RegDwight just offered *dealt with* and *had*. I submit that *had* may not be particular enough, and has the same Beavis and Butthead problem that *handled* does. *Dealt with* may be applicable, but may have connotations that are too severe. One "deals with" problems, and might say a certain person should be "dealt with" if he causes trouble, etc.

Answer (score 12):

"Rung up", "Checked out", or "Processed" could all work.  "Rung up" is the most colloquial but also the most cashier-specific, and feels to me like the best fit; "checked out" has an unfortunate secondary meaning; and "processed" sounds quite impersonal, which may also be appropriate for some cashiers....

Answer (score 4):

Cashiers themselves seem to use "ring up" as in "I can ring you up over here, sir" when they want you to switch lines.

Answer (score 3):

Helped, served, rung up, had, assisted?

Answer (score 2):

How about [*dealt with*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deal_with) or simply [*had*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deal_with)?

Answer (score 1):

For cashiers, you can use the statement "Handle financial transaction"
Great if trying to pursue a professional resume.

Answer (score 0):

I would use *helped*.

Comment: Re off-topic question: Because a good answer rarely consists of a single word. For example, you could improve this one by adding an explanation of why you think this word is the best fit for the OP's criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You wait in the checkout line. You put your items on the checkout counter, and the cashier does the checkout. The verb is a phrasal verb - they checked out 80 people in one shift.

[check out](https://www.google.com/search?q=checked-out+meaning+paid&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=checked-out+meaning+paid&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i546l2j0i30i546j0i546.19328j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)